# How to ignore request-response pairs with a 304 status code in Burp?

Tags: burp-suite

I'm using Burp Pro to assess a web application that sends a requests to an particular endpoint every second. This responds to almost every request with a `304 Not Modified` status code, and I'd rather not have to dig through them in my proxy history. I've tried to set `Project Options: HTTP: Streaming Responses` to that particular endpoint, but to no avail.

I don't want to block the endpoint outright, because when it returns a 200 status code I want to know, but I'm not seeing any configurations that would help.

Ideally I could just ignore all 304 responses, but again, I'm not seeing an obvious way to configure that.

Answer (score 1):

I would try playing with the filter settings in the HTTP History tab:

Filter out 3xx response codes:

[image: Burp filter out 3xx responses]

Or filter out the text "Not Modified", assuming you don't need to text search for anything else:

[image: Burp filter out specific next]

Comment: That's a start, but in both of those cases l'm stuck with a bunch of 304s in the logs that l don't want in there to begin with.

Comment: What do you mean "in the logs". Burp does not have "logs" ?

Comment: There is a setting to only record traffic that is "in scope", but that only lets you configure host / ip / port but the Scope does not give filtering based on message content. I think the best you can do is to filter down what is displayed in the HTTP History tab.

Comment: What is Proxy History if not a log? But anyways, that's kinda disappointing. Easier ways of throwing out data that you _know_ you will not want to sift through later would be really useful. 

Thanks for the help

Comment: Meh, I find it's a bit like Wireshark; capture everything so that you have a complete record of the traffic, but set view filters so it's easier on your eyeballs. \*shrug\* I suppose if there's so much junk traffic that Burp is using 10's of GBs of RAM then that would be a problem.